# How to catch click events on HTML object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My intention is to catch click events on an `<object/>` embedding a `Flash` file

This is what I've tried so far :

```
<div class="myban" data-go="http://google.com">
    <object class="myban" data="index.swf>"></object>
</div>
<script>
$('.myban').click(function() {
    var us = $(this).data('go');
    window.open(us, '_blank');
    return false;
})
</script>
```

Comment: clicks on objects usually aren't available to the browser. they go straight to the object

Comment: It's not what you asked for, but I must tell you: Flash is dead.

Comment: I've improved the question's content wording & revised the title

Comment: @ThomasLandauer except my wife is sat next to me playing Flash games ;)

Comment: this is still a relevant question. I want to capture a click from an svg _embedded in an object tag_. I hope there is still an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Except the fact that Flash is dead, You should either wrap your object with a `<a>` tag, which won't be correct markup as you should not wrap block element with inline element but it works.

Other workaround is to have a floating `<a>` above the flash object taking full dimension and positioned absolute.